# How to get exact current location for google maps with accuracy less than 1 meter, Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cllocationmanager, swift4

I am working on construction project and for that I want to fetch exact current location which must satisfy the accuracy withing the 1 meter. I am using google maps with SDK "CLLocationManager" and I am getting the current location but the location is not exact, it has some (+/-)5 meters to (+/-)10 meters error in location. **I want the exact/accurate current location which should not exceeds the location accuracy error more than a feet.**
Please help me out to fetch EXACT CURRENT LOCATION. 
Also, is there any third party library, any hardware device (which I can connect to iOS device.) or anything else, please let me know.
Your valuable comment will be most appreciate.

**Edited:-**

Here I am sharing my code to get the current location using CLLocationManager:

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
     super.viewDidLoad()

     self.locationManager = CLLocationManager() 
     self.locationManager.delegate = self 
     self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest 
     self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
     self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
     self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{            
     let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: manager.location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: manager.location!.coordinate.longitude)
     marker.position = position 
     print("position:",position)
}
```

Thank you..

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @Mia: Edited and posted my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
   guard let location = manager.location else{
        return
    }
   var currentLocationCoordinate = location.coordinate
}
```

using this delegate function you will get the current location

Comment: :Thnx for your input but, please read carefully my question. I am talking about location "Accuracy".

Comment: self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation

Comment: Yes, I have tested all the Accuracies but not getting the exact/accurate location. I need the exact current location which should not exceeds the error more than a feet.

Answer (score -1):

You can use external gps if you want to get the exact location, with the help of device you will always get this fluctuation. You can also set your location accuracy to best.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LocationBestPractices.html

Comment: Hi Deepak, Thanx for valuable input. I gone through your link. But, unfortunately it not that helpful for me. Your asking for external gps device, so do you have any idea about such device that will provide me exact/accurate current location which should not exceeds the location error more than a feet.?

Comment: There are so many products in the market available for this and they provide there SDK's too.

https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dmobile&field-keywords=extenal+gps

Answer (score -1):

You should always relay on GPS for accurate location. You can set locationManager.desireAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest. It will call you locationManager didUpdateLocation with the location array with each location having its accuracy you can apply your logic here.

Be alert to call  locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()  when you done with desire accuracy location.

e.g

```
let horizontalAccuracy: Double = 20.0
let howRecent = location.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow
    guard CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(location.coordinate),
      location.horizontalAccuracy > 0,
      location.horizontalAccuracy < horizontalAccuracy,
      abs(howRecent) < 10 else { return false }
    return true

  }
```